# torch find indices of matching rows in 2 2D tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have two 2D tensors, in different length, both are different subsets of the same original 2d tensor and I would like to find all the matching "rows"
e.g

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[3,3,3]
B = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[4,4,4]]
torch.2dintersect(A,B) -> [0,2] (the indecies of A that B also have)
```

I've only see numpy solutions, that use dtype as dicts, and does not work for pytorch.

Here is how I do it in numpy

```
arr1 = edge_index_dense.numpy().view(np.int32)
arr2 = edge_index2_dense.numpy().view(np.int32)
arr1_view = arr1.view([('', arr1.dtype)] * arr1.shape[1])
arr2_view = arr2.view([('', arr2.dtype)] * arr2.shape[1])
intersected = np.intersect1d(arr1_view, arr2_view, return_indices=True)
```

Comment: could you present a desired result, and it means?

Comment: I've added it, on the tensors A,B, the output are the indices 0,2, as they intersect in those rows

Answer (score 5):

This answer was posted before the OP updated the question with other restrictions that changed the problem quite a bit.

**TL;DR** You can do something like this:

```py
torch.where((A == B).all(dim=1))[0]
```

---

First, assuming you have:

```py
import torch
A = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3],[4,4,4],[7,8,9]])
```

We can check that `A == B` returns:

```
>>> A == B
tensor([[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]])
```

So, what we want is: the rows in which they are all `True`. For that, we can use the `.all()` operation and specify the dimension of interest, in our case `1`:

```
>>> (A == B).all(dim=1)
tensor([ True, False,  True])
```

What you actually want to know is where the `True`s are. For that, we can get the first output of the `torch.where()` function:

```
>>> torch.where((A == B).all(dim=1))[0]
tensor([0, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I meant they may have a different length, and the order may be different.

Comment: @DsCpp Oh, I see. Then it is a completely different problem. Post the NumPy solutions that you have found. It will be easier to understand all your restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

If A and B are 2D tensors, the following code finds the indices such that `A[indices] == B`. If multiple indices satisfy this condition, the first index found is returned. If not all elements of B are present in A, the corresponding index is ignored.

```
values, indices = torch.topk(((A.t() == B.unsqueeze(-1)).all(dim=1)).int(), 1, 1)
indices = indices[values!=0]
# indices = tensor([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows of the two tensors are different, then we cannot compare the tensors directly. We have to first add a dummy dimension on one of the tensors. Step by step:

0. Create the tensors

```py
A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[3,3,3]])
B = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[4,4,4]])
```

1. Add dummy dimension and obtain a pairwise comparison:

```py
B == A.unsqueeze(1)
```

The output will be a 4x3x3 tensor where each of the 4 `i` sub-tensors is `A[i] == B`.

2. Obtain the tensor indicating which indices have a perfect "row" match:

```py
(B == A.unsqueeze(1)).all(-1)
```

The output is a 4x3 tensor. The rows with a `True` element contain a perfect row match.

3. Get rows with a perfect match:

```py
(B == A.unsqueeze(1)).all(-1).any(-1)
```

4. Finally, get the indices of the rows in `A` with matches in `B`:

```py
torch.where((B == A.unsqueeze(1)).all(-1).any(-1))[0]
>> tensor([0, 2])
```

---

To get the indices of the rows in B with matches in A, simply swap the tensors:

```py
torch.where((A == B.unsqueeze(1)).all(-1).any(-1))[0]
>> tensor([0, 1])
```

---

There is a similar numpy version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64219670/6194082), and my answer is very much inspired by [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221423/6194082) by [Ehsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975981/ehsan).