# PyTorch find indices of matching rows between two large tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two 2D tensors, `A` and `B`. I would like to write a function `find_indices(A, B)` which returns a 1D tensor that contains the indices of rows in `A` which also appears in `B`. Also, the function should avoid using `for` loop for parallelization. For example:

```py
import torch

A = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]).cuda()
B = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 6], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5]]).cuda()

indices1 = find_indices(A, B)  # tensor([0, 2])
indices2 = find_indices(B, A)  # tensor([0, 3])

assert A[indices1].equal(B[indices2])
```

Assume that:

- All the rows in `A` and `B` are unique.
- Rows in `A` and `B` are both sorted. So the same two rows appear in the same order in `A` and `B`.
- `len(A)` and `len(B)` are ~200k.

I have tried this method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60494505/17495278:

```py
values, indices = torch.topk(((A.t() == B.unsqueeze(-1)).all(dim=1)).int(), 1, 1)
indices = indices[values!=0]
# indices = tensor([0, 2])
```

It gives accurate answer for small scale input. But for my use case, it takes >100 GB memory and raises CUDA out of memory error. Is there another way to achieve this with reasonable memory cost (say under 1 GB)?

Comment: You could do the same as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays

Comment: @Toyo Thanks, but there is a for loop in this answer.

Comment: go the the accepted answer. No for loop there.

Comment: oh sorry, yes you are right. There is one in the list comprehension.

Comment: @Toyo Thanks! This is what I'm looking for. Sorry for misreading.

Comment: @Toyo The for loop is on the dimension of col (3) so actually no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: For anyone looking for the answer, this is the pure PyTorch, GPU-only method.

```py
_, idx, counts = torch.cat([A, B], dim=0).unique(
    dim=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
mask = torch.isin(idx, torch.where(counts.gt(1))[0])
mask1 = mask[:len(A)]  # tensor([ True, False,  True], device='cuda:0')
mask2 = mask[len(A):]  # tensor([ True, False, False,  True], device='cuda:0')

assert A[mask1].equal(B[mask2])
```

This method gives True/False mask instead of indices, which is also sufficient for tensor indexing. If you really need numerical indices, they can be acquired by

```py
indices1 = torch.arange(len(mask1))[mask1]  # tensor([0, 2])
indices2 = torch.arange(len(mask2))[mask2]  # tensor([0, 3])
```

---

Original answer (with numpy on CPU and GPU/CPU data transfer, can be 100x slower)

```py
import numpy as np

A_npy = A.cpu().numpy()
B_npy = B.cpu().numpy()
nrows, ncols = A_npy.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
       'formats':ncols * [A_npy.dtype]}
_, indices1, indices2 = np.intersect1d(A_npy.view(dtype), B_npy.view(dtype),
                                       return_indices=True)

print(indices1)  # [0 2]
print(indices2)  # [0 3]
assert A[indices1].equal(B[indices2])
```

This method uses `numpy.intersect1d` and returns the result as a `numpy.ndarray`. PyTorch tensor supports indexing with numpy array anyway so this works for me. The only flaw now is the overhead of data transfer between GPU and CPU.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317403/17495278

Credit: [@Toyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736312/toyo), [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington)